# How to set an anonymous child scope setting in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the correct way to solve the following problem:

I have something like this:

```
<div ng-click="!showAll">Show All</div>
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos">
    <div ng-click="!showSubItems">Do Stuff</div>
    <div ng-show="showSubItems">
        <div ng-repeat="bar in foo.bars">
            <div>{{bar.stuff}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want the show all to go through each bar item and expand it by changing the showSubItems. I've googled around and the only answer I found deals with when the children scopes have a controller. In my case I don't have an explicit controller for the scopes of the children item since they are very basic. Is there a way to tell each child scope that is should set showSubItems=true?

I tried doing `<div ng-show="showSubItems||showAll">`, but then I can't collapse the children items individually once they are open. I could put something on the foo model, but that seems like the incorrect way of handling this since it's adding data to a model when the model doesn't have any knowledge or concern about the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of without using controllers is to iterate over the child scopes using $$childHead and set showSubItems to true. While this works, it's not really "correct" to access $$childHead since it should be considered private to AngularJS. Here's how the showAll looks like:

```
$scope.showAll = function () {
    var childScope = $scope.$$childHead;
    while (childScope) {
        childScope.showSubItems = true;
        childScope = childScope.$$nextSibling;
    }
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JFcKs/

A more correct solution in my opinion would be to give each foo a controller which listens to a "showAll" event which is broadcasted by the parent scope when show all is clicked.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/v586a/

Answer (score 1):

Try this...I did not how your collections look like. So I made up simple string array.

```
<div ng-controller="MyTestController">
<div ng-click="showAll = !showAll" ng-init="showAll=false">Show All</div>
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos">
    <div ng-click="showSubItems = !showSubItems" ng-init="showSubItems=false">Do Stuff</div>
    <div ng-show="showSubItems || showAll">
        <div ng-repeat="bar in bars">
            <div>{{bar}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    WebPortal.controller('MyTestController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.foos = ['Foo1', 'Foo2', 'Foo3'];
        $scope.bars = ['Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3'];
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to put in the original code that bar is a child of foo. I tried the || statement but then they are always shown and can't be closed until the button is clicked again.